# NsMutable array retain count

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

i used the instruments to find leaks in my iphone app and i found that i have leak in this line in my code

> tableViewController.dataSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc]  initWithArray:[subjects_dic allKeys]];

the property dataSource defined as retain.
is this a mistake ?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Break it up:

```
NSMutableArray *mutArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[subjects_dic allKeys]];
[tableViewController setDataSource:mutArray];
[mutArray release];
```

It's the same pattern you use for creating, pushing, and releasing Views from the Navigation Controller.

Answer (score 2):

If you specify retain in your property declaration, then anything you assign to that property will be retained.

So in your example, you have two options:

1. Instead of creating a new array with the alloc/init approach, you can simply use `[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[subjects_dic allKeys]];`
2. Release the property once after setting it. This option isn't as good an idea, as it may cause a crash if the property's memory management is changed in the future and this release is forgotten about.

I'd recommend option 1.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```
// mutableCopy implicitly retains the array returned by allKeys
NSMutableArray *mutArray = [[subjects_dic allKeys] mutableCopy];
[tableViewController setDataSource:mutArray]; // @property dataSource retains mutArray
[mutArray release];
```